# Conditional statement in GAE Go template package

Tags: google-app-engine, templates, go, conditional-statements

How is it possible to perform a conditional statement in html template in GAE GO? I was trying to accomplish this to make an option selected in a select html tag:

```
<select name=".Grade">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1" {{ if .Grade="1" }} selected="selected" {{ end }}>Grade One</option>
          <option value="2" {{ if .Grade="2" }} selected="selected" {{ end }}>Grade Two</option>
          <option value="3" {{ if .Grade="3" }} selected="selected" {{ end }}>Grade Three</option>
          <option value="4" {{ if .Grade="4" }} selected="selected" {{ end }}>Grade Four</option>
          <option value="5" {{ if .Grade="5" }} selected="selected" {{ end }}>Grade Five</option>
          <option value="6" {{ if .Grade="6" }} selected="selected" {{ end }}>Grade Six</option>
</select>
```

There is

```
{{ if .Grade }} selected="selected" {{ end }}
```

in the reference doc but this only evaluates to true if `.Grade` has value. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no equality statement in the base template package.
Here is an [interesting discussion from golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/OEdSDgEC7js) about it.

You have several possibilities:

- define an external function for equality, like the one Russ Cox suggests in the golang-nuts thread and test it with a `if` condition
- use something the base template package can understand (see my code below)
- remove some logic from the template: instead of having 6 hardcoded fields, you could construct a datatype with a `selected` boolean field and give an array of 6 of these objects to a template with a `range` statement

I recreated your example by using a slice of booleans:

```
func main() {
    temp,err := template.ParseFiles("template.html")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    g := make([]bool, 7)
    g[1] = true
    temp.Execute(os.Stdout, &g)
}
```

A line in the template looks like this:

```
<option value="3"{{ if index . 3 }} selected="selected"{{ end }}>Grade Three</option>
```

This doesn't look so good to me. But I'd say that all solutions have their drawbacks and that this is a matter of taste (the third solution should be cleaner but might be considered overkill for such a simple thing).

**Edit (2013/12/11)**

In [Go 1.2](http://golang.org/doc/go1.2) ([released on 2013/12/01](http://blog.golang.org/go12)), the [template engine](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/text/template) has been updated and includes new operators, including comparison. This now should work as expected:

```
{{if eq .Grade 1 }} selected="selected" {{end}}
```

You can still choose to keep as few logic as possible in your templates, though.